# Having multiple replacement of alphabets within the for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace characters in a sentence using a for loop (more like decrypting a message) using giving cipherKey.

I managed to set both orgKey and cipherKey to align and replace each other (please see the code below for clear understanding regarding this).

```
orgKey = [list]
cipherKey = [list]
message = "some secret message"

for i in range (len(orgKey)):
    message = message.replace(cipherKey[i], orgKey[i])
    print(message)
```

I was expecting a clean message with replaced letters, but since `"message = message.replace(cipherKey[i], orgKey[i])` line is included in for loop, it replaced each letter in the length of `orgKey`.
What would be the best, cleaner method with this?

Comment: you can use len(message) as your range i.e. `for i in range (len(message)):`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
orgKey = [list]
cipherKey = [list]
message = "some secret message"

message_encrypt = ''
dictionary = dict(zip(orgKey, cipherKey))
for char in message:
    message_encrypt += dictionary.get(char,' ')
print(message_encrypt)
```

Only if the lists have the same length.